# Will Evoke trigger on a creature that's returned to the battlefield from the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When a spell or ability returns a card with Evoke from i.e. the graveyard to the battlefield, will it's Evoke ability trigger, or does it only trigger when it enters the battlefield from the stack, being cast with it's Evoke cost paid?

For example, if I blink [Nevermaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNevermaker%5d) using [Brago, King Eternal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrago%2c%20King%20Eternal%5d)s ability, would Evoke trigger when it re-enters the battlefield?

Comment: Evoke allows to cast a creature for an alternative cost at the price of sacrificing it when it comes into play.

Are you sure you're not mistaking it for another keyword ?

Comment: Or are you talking about what happens when a creature with evoke leave then re-enter the battlefield because of some effect ?

Comment: Yes @Ydrasaal, I am sure I am talking about `evoke`.

Comment: Can the down votes explain their vote, I do not understand...

Comment: The downvotes were because your question was not clear, but it is now fixed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A creature will never be considered "evoked" when entering the battlefield in any other situation than being cast.

Here's what the rules says about Evoke:

> **702.73a** [...] “Evoke [cost]” means “You may cast this card by paying [cost] rather than paying its mana cost” and “When this permanent enters the battlefield, if its evoke cost was paid, its controller sacrifices it.” [...]

Evoke adds two things to the card :

The first is an alternative cost, meaning it can only be used at any time you would be able to play the card by paying its mana cost.

The second (the sacrifice part) is a triggered ability for the creature, that will trigger when entering the battlefield.
This trigger will make the controller of the creature sacrifice it, if and only if the Evoke alternative cost has been paid.

If a creature with Evoke was played paying it's Evoke cost, then leave the battlefield and later comes back (for example from [Acrobatic Maneuver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAcrobatic%20Maneuver%5d) or [Reanimate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bReanimate%5d)), it will be a completely new object, which Evoke cost hasn't been paid, and so the Evoke trigger won't make it's controller sacrifice it.

Comment: The creature will still have the triggered ability (which you mention not being the case on two instances), however it won't trigger.

Comment: Oh right. I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out where the "sacrificed at end of turn" ability in your last paragraph is coming from. As far as I can tell (and I might be skipping over something), none of the cards involved have "end of turn" printed on them. If you just meant "sacrificed" and you are talking about the Evoke ability, then it's important to note that the ability *will* still trigger, but nothing will happen when it resolves.

Comment: @Rainbolt Thanks, it's fixed (Dunno where that came from, probably mixed up Evoke and Dash)